# Get URL variable from ASP page

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have an iframe on my page and I would like to add a variable to the iframe source only if the variable is present in the url from my page. For example, if someone visits index.asp I just want the iframe source to be `src="iframe.php` but if someone visit index.asp?id=123 then I would like the iframe source to be `iframe.php?id=123`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%

Dim iFrameSrc

Dim id
id = Request.QueryString("Id")
If( Len( id ) > 0 ) Then

    iFrameSrc = "iframe.php?id=" & id

Else
    iFrameSrc = "iframe.php"
End If

%>

<iframe src="<%= iFrameSrc %>" />
```

Note **that this code is unsafe and is vulnerable to cross-site-scripting. You will need to ensure that the `id` variable is safe before rendering**.

Comment: Since in this case the ID appears to be an integer something like `CLng(id)` should take care of safety.